# What is the "Quorum" badge?

Tags: support, badges

I really can't get the point why I was awarded the "quorum" badge. What does the "quorum" badge represent? Any suggestion..

Comment: You're well on your way to *Convention*!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=quorum

> **Quorum** (n)
>
> a gathering of the minimal number of members of an organization to conduct business

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quorum

> **quorum** (plural quorums)
>
> The minimum number of members required for a group to officially conduct business and to cast binding votes, often but not necessarily a majority or supermajority.
>
> *"We can discuss the issue tonight, but cannot vote until we have a quorum."*

Check out the https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq , and even in the Stack Overflow FAQ proper it says

> If you want to talk about the site itself, please don't do it here. Visit our meta-discussion site where you can talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, suggest a feature, or generally discuss how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 8):

[The description](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) is pretty clear:

"One post with score of 2 on meta"

where *meta* is the meta site of that specific Stack Exchange site.

Additionally, there's a silver version of that badge named "Convention" which is defined to be:

"10 posts with score of 2 on meta"

Comment: AND there is a **link to meta** in the badge description itself!

Comment: I guess it also requires that the post is NOT tagged as `community wiki`, which might be a bit confusing when you look at your posts, specially on meta, where a lot of questions that are answered a lot is just that... So you might have a lot of posts that has more than 2 rep. and you still haven't got the Qourum badge because they are `community wiki`